# Map a tinyint as boolean hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, types

I have a BOOLEAN type in a MySQL table (TINYINT(1)) and I'm trying to map the boolean field in an entity but this generates an exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in maegul.users for column admin. Found: bit, expected: boolean
```

I changed the field in my entity to byte and make the respective changes so it acts a boolean, and I get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in maegul.users for column admin. Found: bit, expected: tinyint
```

I tried using the `@Type` annotation on the field:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
```

but I get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in maegul.users for column admin. Found: bit, expected: integer
```

Comment: probably some useful info [here](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-468).

Comment: @alvinbaena: any correct answer below??

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question which has been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383169/hibernate-jpa-mysql-and-tinyint1-for-boolean-instead-of-bit-or-char/10224905#10224905

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From what I read here :

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in maegul.users for column admin. Found: bit, expected: integer

It seems Hibernate is expecting an integer and got a bit.

Which mean your annotation is now correct :

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
```

But maybe it has updated your database to set as Bit instead of integer, thus the error.

If you really need a TinyInt, you can use `@Type` AND `@Column`, to set as Integer, of type TinyInt :

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
public boolean admin = true;
```

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this, and the project where this question was relevant is long ago lost. I really don't recall how I solved this, but seeing as some people have found this answer to be appropiate I'll accept it.

Comment: Yep. I had the same error but my column was a `bit`. I used this solution but with `BIT` instead of `TINYINT` in the `columnDefinition` and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Better use `BIT(1)` instead of `TINYINT(1)`

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
private boolean flag = false;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it from Dialect which will not require tedious col level annotation at all places:

```
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect;
import java.sql.Types;

public class PostgresCustomConversionDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {

    public PostgresCustomConversionDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerColumnType( Types.BIT, "numeric(1, 0)" );
        this.registerColumnType( Types.BOOLEAN, "numeric(1, 0)" );
    }

    public String toBooleanValueString(boolean bool) {
        return bool ? "1" : "0";
    }

}
```

Then use this custom dialect as postgres dialect in - "hibernate.dialect"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  <property name="isPaymentReceived" type="java.lang.Boolean">
  <column name="IS_PAYMENT_RECEIVED" sql-type="tinyint"/>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by adding "transformedBitIsBoolean=true" to my MySQL connection string.

See this question: ["Found: bit, expected: boolean" after Hibernate 4 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667965/found-bit-expected-boolean-after-hibernate-4-upgrade)

And this forum post: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6935

Answer (score 1):

@Type annotation is hibernate annotation
to use with JPA, one can use ColumnDefiniton Attribute.

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
private boolean isTrue;
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with mapping it as an int and using an accessor (isAdmin) to get the boolean value. I hope you're obscuring the actual type anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping it as org.hibernate.type.BooleanType might work.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work gives the same exception as if it was a boolean with no annotation

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar situation with hibernate today and ended up having mysql data type as tinyint(1) and declared hibernate type as boolean and it did the trick

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

Define your column as bit(1)

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (bool_column BIT(1));
```

Define your entity property as boolean

Map the property like this

```
@Column(name = "bool_column", columnDefinition = "BIT")
public boolean boolField;
```

I think this way is simpler and in addition you stick to the jpa standard.

I have this working with MySQL and Hibernate 5.