# "Found: bit, expected: boolean" after Hibernate 4 upgrade

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hsqldb, hibernate-4.x

I'm trying to upgrade from Hibernate 3.6.5 to 4.0 (and from Spring 3.0.5 to 3.1 which is required for Hibernate 4 support).

Now, with both MySQL and HSQL, I'm running into this problem with persistent boolean fields:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
Wrong column type in PUBLIC.PUBLIC.EVENT for column Checked. Found: bit, expected: boolean
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1775)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:184)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:314)
```

JPA [`@Entity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html) and [`@Column`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotations are used in domain objects, and the problematic fields look like this:

```
@Column(name = "Checked")
private boolean checked;
```

HSQL schema:

```
Checked bit default 0 not null,
```

MySQL schema:

```
`Checked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
```

**What is the most straightforward way to solve this while sticking with Hibernate 4**? Should I change the database schema, Hibernate configs, or domain class annotations?

I have no idea if the code and configuration was fully "correct" before, but at least it worked fine with Hibernate 3.

Comment: With HSQL, changing "bit" to "boolean" in the schema file *seems* to help (i.e., I then run into a different Hibernate 4 problem). That's a bit strange though, as [HSQL documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#datatypes-section) gives the impression that  BOOLEAN and BIT are equivalent.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I worked this out by adding `columnDefinition = "BIT"` to the @Column line.

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "B", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
public boolean isB() {
    return b;
}
```

Its defined as a 'BIT(1)' in the DB as well. Also worked with TINYINT. This is the easiest solution I've found since the change is super-minor and no need to touch the DB.

Using: MySQL Server 5.5.13, Hibernate 4.1.1, JDK 1.6

Comment: No longer needed in Hibernate version 4.3.0+

Comment: this solution will work - however it's not a fix for a root problem - which is mysql server itself - consider adding 'transformedBitIsBoolean' flag to your datasource URL as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22200375/1694963

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem and I extended the Dialect to take into account the fact that mysql treats boolean as an alias of bit.

```
public class Mysql5BitBooleanDialect extends MySQL5Dialect{     
    public Mysql5BitBooleanDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType( java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN, "bit" );        
    }       
}
```

I don't use longer bit() fields (to represent for example byte[]) so this might break that.

Comment: This seems like (another) big type-related oversight in Hibernate's MySQL dialect.  I put off upgrading when 4.0 was released and I'm surprised it hasn't been addressed a year later.  But thanks for the tip.  Extending the dialect and updating persistence.xml seems much better than adding a columnDefinition any time I annotate a boolean field.  I'm using Hibernate as a JPA implementation and I want to keep the non-configuration bits as implementation-neutral as possible.

Comment: Yet 6 months later the problem is still there. The worst is that the schema generated by hibernate2ddl itself uses boolean with MySQL. So the Hibernate-generated schema cannot be validated by Hibernate :(

Comment: At last it should be corrected in the next release (4.3.0): https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6935

Answer (score 11):

I was able to solve this issue by adding `transformedBitIsBoolean=true` to my MySQL connection string. See here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6935

Comment: this is much better then coding as bit :-)

Comment: Worked for me (Hibernate 4.1.x). Because it was not obvious to me at first what is meant here: In persistence.xml: <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?transformedBitIs‌​Boolean=true"/>

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in a similar question here :

[Hibernate JPA, MySQL and TinyInt(1) for Boolean instead of bit or char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383169/hibernate-jpa-mysql-and-tinyint1-for-boolean-instead-of-bit-or-char/10224905#10224905)

Your problem could be a bit more complicated as you use HSQL DB at the same time, but you can take a look and try it anyway !

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem 
i also got org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type ... Found: bit, expected: boolean

on BooleanType in hibernate 4 they changed the Ctor to

```
public BooleanType() {
    this( org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BooleanTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, BooleanTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE );
}
```

instead of old versions

```
public BooleanType() {
    this( BitTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, BooleanTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE );
}
```

Comment: Um, so what is the solution? Quoting my question: "What is the most straightforward way to solve this while sticking with Hibernate 4? Should I change the database schema, Hibernate configs, or domain class annotations?"

Comment: it's not the answer to the question.