# How to properly map the DTOs in Hibernate so that SessionFactory initializes properly?

Tags: java, hibernate

This might be a very basic issues but I tried many things but getting issues with all. Daddies please ignore.

**CASE 1:**

When I mention my mappings in hibernate.cfg.xml as below:

```
<mapping class="com.tm.midservice.db.dto.User"/>
<mapping class="com.tm.midservice.db.dto.Company"/>
```

I get the following errors.

```
INFO  - org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata - table found: demodb.company
INFO  - org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata - columns: [analytics_feature_enabled,     source_domain, currency, id, updated_at, source, token, name, domain, created_at, active, mid]
SessionFactory initial creation error.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type: active, expected: bit`
```

The column I have described in my DTO is as :

```
@Column(name = "active")
private boolean active;
```

**(EDIT 1)**

Tried the below thing, but did not work:

```
@Type(type="true_false")
@Column(name="active", columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0")
private boolean active;
```

gives exception as:

```
SessionFactory initial creation error.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type: active, expected: TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0
```

**(EDIT 2)**

Found something at: ["Found: bit, expected: boolean" after Hibernate 4 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667965/found-bit-expected-boolean-after-hibernate-4-upgrade)

```
@Column(name="active", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
private boolean active;
```

gives exception as:

```
SessionFactory initial creation error.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type: active, expected: BIT
```

**(EDIT 3)**

Tried something as:

```
public class Mysql5BitBooleanDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {
  public Mysql5BitBooleanDialect() {
    super();
    registerColumnType( Types.BOOLEAN, "bit" );
  }
}
```

This class does get invoked, but exception does not go.

**CASE 2** :

When I do not give the mapping in cfg file and try to run my application, the sessionFactory initializes and all but when I try to do any database operations I get error as :

```
hibernate mapping exception unknown entity
```

Ideally I should not be giving any mapping definitions as the DTO has got the annotations for that `[@Entity & @Table (name = "User")]`.

How do I configure things properly? Any thing I am missing here? I am so stuck.

Comment: The column that is storing the active field is of the wrong type. Hibernate expects the type to be of type `bit` (ie 1 or 0). This is how most databases represent boolean's

Comment: can you please refer to my latest edit? Tried something with `active` field but did not work.

Comment: Column definition won't do anything, you want a `@Type` annotation. That will change what Hibernate is expecting

Comment: what to do here? How does this thing go?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the database table, which I completely ignored. The TinyInt field was of size 11, changing which to 1 solved the issue.