# HSQL + Hibernate Exception: Wrong column type: Found: double, expected: float

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I am using in-memory HSQL (HSQLDB) with Hibernate for all my unit tests, because it is very fast.  I have a table with a column defined as follows:

```
float qw;
```

When hibernate starts, I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in MyTable for column qw. 
Found: double, expected: float
```

Why does it find `double` when the column is declared as `float`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is happening due to *a series of unfortunate events*.

1. The problem begins with the fact that HSQLDB does not support the
   `float` data type.

   <sup>(Duh? Yes, I know, but [Documentation
   here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html).)</sup>
2. The problem starts becoming ugly due to the fact that HSQLDB does
   not simply ***fail*** when you specify a `float` column, but it
   silently re-interprets it as `double`. If you later query the type
   of that column, you will find that it is not `float`, it is
   `double`.

   <sup>A typical example of programmers applying their misguided
   notions of "defensive programming", creating far more trouble than
   they are saving. HSQLDB is essentially pretending to the
   unsuspecting programmer that everything went fine, but it is only
   trolling them: nothing went fine, and there will be trouble.</sup>
3. Then, later, hibernate finds this column to be `double`, while it
   expects it to be `float`, and it is not smart enough to know that
   `float` *is assignable* from `double`, so it fails.

   <sup>Everyone knows that a `double` is better than a `float`, so
   hibernate should actually be *happy* that it found a `double` while
   all it needed was a `float`, right? --but no, hibernate will not
   have any of that: when it expects a `float`, nothing but a `float`
   will do.</sup>
4. Then, there is this funny thing about hibernate supposedly having
   built-in support for HSQLDB, as evidenced by the fact that it
   includes a `class org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect`, but ***the
   dialect does not take care of floats.***

   <sup>So, they don't believe that a data type incompatibility is a
   dialect issue? they never tested it with floats? I don't know what
   to suppose, but the truth of the matter is that the hibernate
   dialect for HSQLDB does not provide any correction for this
   problem.</sup>

So, what can we do?

One possible solution to the problem is to create our own hibernate dialect for HSQLDB, in which we correct this discrepancy.

In the past I came across a similar problem with MySQL and `boolean` vs. `bit`, (see this question: ["Found: bit, expected: boolean" after Hibernate 4 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8667965/773113)) so for HSQLDB I solved the problem with `float` vs. `double` by declaring my own HSQLDB dialect for hibernate:

```
/**
 * 'Fixed' HSQL Dialect.
 *
 * PEARL: HSQL seems to have a problem with floats.  We remedy this here.
 * See https://stackoverflow.com/q/28480714/773113
 *
 * PEARL: this class must be public, not package-private, and it must have a 
 * public constructor, otherwise hibernate won't be able to instantiate it.
 */
public class FixedHsqlDialect extends HSQLDialect
{
    public FixedHsqlDialect()
    {
        registerColumnType( java.sql.Types.FLOAT, "double" );
    }
}
```

And using it as follows:

```
ejb3cfg.setProperty( "hibernate.dialect", FixedHsqlDialect.class.getName() );
    //Instead of: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect.class.getName();
```