# Hibernate validation on Derby: Wrong column type for column. Found: double, expected: float

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, derby

I'm developing a java web app that is supposed to work both with a MySQL database and an embedded database (So we've selected Derby for that).

When running with Derby, on hibernate validation of the model, I get the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in .ROOT.BATCH for column unitPrice. Found: real, expected: float
```

The column in the database is declared as FLOAT(12).

The property is declared as

```
private float unitPrice;
```

In Derby, I've tried to declare it with FLOAT and FLOAT(23), but get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Use hsqldb instead (http://hsqldb.org/)

Comment: Why? What are the benefits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HSQL + Hibernate Exception: Wrong column type: Found: double, expected: float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480714/hsql-hibernate-exception-wrong-column-type-found-double-expected-float)